# Can I get a Minecraft server level from a client?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built a nice level, and now it's gone.  But I remembered that someone connected to my computer when I opened to LAN and played for a while.  Would the level be stored on their computer?

Comment: The level is only loaded temp on the RAM. Once the data is no longer in use, it will be overwritten by another program that needs the ram. So there's a 100% chance that's it's been overwritten, sadly. Unless said person hasn't used his computer after that, but, windows would still use it. :(

Comment: Shouldn't there be a real copy of that map in /saves/ of the host computer?

Comment: @dly he's hosting through LAN, and of he didn't keep backups then it's gone

Comment: @Alex, yes the client won't have a local copy, but the map ought to be physically hosted somewhere, otherwise it would eat a lot of ram. I'm not sure how it exactly works on LAN games, but isn't that just a single player game with open LAN port?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot get it back from client. Because you never gave the whole level to the client. You did open to LAN, which sends only required chunks to client's ram.

The only option you have is some recovery software. there are bunch of them.

**NOTE:-  If you are running a server(open to LAN as well) then make backup every day. Use a batch file to do so.**

Comment: If the user has already used some of his RAM there's a good chance it's overwritten.

Comment: Its pointless to get back the level from RAM. because the level file will NOT be loaded in the level format it was saved in. minecraft will already have assigned all variables to corresponding objects. Even if you manage to save RAM data to disk , there is high chance of file being corrupt. So the best option is go to a file recovery application